# Creating Mulitlanguage Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What would be the best practice to write a chrome extension in multiple languages?
I know about the chrome.i18n infrastructure to provide language-specific resources WITHIN the extension.

But in the chrome store I can only offer ONE description. Now I want to offer my plugin in two languages: german/english

Should I just upload two versions with the same name and different language settings? Is that even possible?

Does the store automaticly only display one of those two extensions corresponding to the users language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesnt appear to be a way to provide store descriptions in multiple languages, I had the same problem recently. The problem with publishing two is that stars and total users will be independent for each. Usually helps to show a large number of users to convince people to install it.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear... Thanks nonetheless :)